# PendingIntent for Incoming call not getting launched for Twilio Android client

Tags: android, android-intent, twilio, android-pendingintent

In the sample application for the Twilio android client,I am not being able to receive incoming calls.I am using node js for the server.The request is being routed between my server and twilio and even I am able to see the call status in the twilio call logs. But when I call a twilio client,nothing is seen on the android device. I think there is a problem with the pendingIntent getting launched. Can anybody help me out?

//MonkeyPhone.java

```
 public void onInitialized() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Twilio SDK is ready");
    try {
                capabilityToken = HttpHelper.httpGet("http://My server/token?client=jenny");
               device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, this);
               Intent intent = new Intent(context, HelloMonkeyActivity.class);
               PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
               device.setIncomingIntent(pendingIntent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG,
                        "Failed to obtain capability token: "
                                + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
```

//HelloMonkeyActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }   

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        Device device=intent.getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        Connection connection= intent.getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);
        Log.i("Hello monkey", "device and connection are:"+device+" :"+connection);

        if(device!=null && connection!=null){
            intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);
            phone.handleIncomingConnections(device, connection);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have implemented code for incoming successfully and I'm getting incoming calls too when I come to a particular activity. But I get Device and connection null when I implement that code into background Service. Have you also done this?

Comment: @anshul..Unfortunately I have not implemented the code for background service.

Comment: Are you getting incoming call successfully? I'm getting an error when I accept it `07-21 00:34:55.811: E/PJSIP(1388): 00:34:55.820    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=302 (Moved Temporarily)
07-21 00:34:55.931: A/PJSIP(1388): 00:34:55.941    pjsua_acc.c  .....Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]
`